# Asp.Net Core 6 Role based Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to manipulate an Asp.Net web app's navigation based on roles.

I have created an Asp.Net (6.0 LTS) Web App with role based authentication based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity. I am able to control access to (Razor)Pages as well as limit acces to not logged in users.

*Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

*Page.cshtml.cs*

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ...;

namespace ...
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {...
```

The check if a user is logged in or not on the navigation level works as follows:

*_LoginPartial.cshtml*

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

My question: How can I manipluate this _LoginPartial.cshtml subpage based on roles? Why show navigation items to users that can not use them in the first place?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.isinrole?view=net-6.0) method:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```